# Shell complains about file permissions when creating a config file

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, file-permissions, packer

I'm not completely sure if I should ask here, over at the [Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) forums or somewhere completely different but, here we go.

I'm using [Packer](https://www.packer.io/) to create a set of images (running Debian 8) for AWS and GCE, and during this process I want to install [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) and set up a config file for it. The image building and package installation goes smooth, but I'm having problems with file permissions when I'm trying to either create the config file or overwrite the existing one.

My Packer Shell Provisioner runs a set of scripts as the user `admin` (as far as I know I can't SSH into this setup with `root`), where as the one I'm having trouble with looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Install HAProxy
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y haproxy

# Create backup of default config file
sudo mv /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg.bak

# Write content over to new config file
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=''
sudo cat << EOF > /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
# Content line 1
# Content line 2
# (...)
EOF
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

The log output gives me this error: `/tmp/script_6508.sh: line 17: /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg: Permission denied`

I've also thought of having a premade config file moved over to the newly created image, but I'm not sure how to do that. And that wouldn't work without writing permissions either, right?

So, does anyone know how I can set up my Shell script to fix this? Or if there is another viable solution?

Comment: Have you checked who owns the file ?

Comment: @123 - Yes, `root` does. Though I'm not sure why, as I'm logged in as `admin` when HAProxy is installed, and thus the folder / default config file is created.

Comment: If you can't `sudo` or use root then no there is nothing you can do regarding that file. I haven't used HAproxy but you can probably manually install it , and set up a different location for the config.

Comment: @123 - Not sure what you mean by "manually". The whole point of this setup is to automatically build images, and this config is a part of that. Is there something else I can write in my script instead of `sudo apt-get install -y haproxy`?

Comment: If you can use sudo for apt-get why can't you use it to change the file owner? By manually i mean download the tar and unpack it somewhere.

Comment: @123 - My best guess is that the `admin` user (auto-generated, not by me) is made to closely resemble `root` but with restrictions in some areas. `apt-get` is mostly automated, so it (kind'a) makes sense to let a user use `apt-get`, but not to let this user change the program/package manually. And I will see if I can make any progress with the .tar.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo chown admin /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the script is the line

```
sudo cat << EOF > /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

The redirection to `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg` happens before `sudo` is called, and thus requires that the file can be created and written to by whatever user is running the script.

Your idea of changing the permissions and ownership of that file solves this issue by making the file writable by the user running the script, but really, you seem to be executing every single line of the script as `root` in any case, so why not just drop all the `sudo`s altogether and run the whole thing as `root`?

```
$ sudo myscript.sh   # executed by the 'admin' user
```

EDIT: Since this script isn't run on the target machine manually, there are two solutions:

1. Go with the `chmod` solution.
2. Write the config file to a temporary file and move it with `sudo`.

The second solution involves changing the line

```
sudo cat << EOF > /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

to

```
cat <<EOF >/tmp/haproxy.cfg.tmp
```

and then after the `EOF` further down

```
sudo cp /tmp/haproxy.cfg.tmp /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
rm -f /tmp/haproxy.cfg.tmp
```

This is arguably "cleaner" than messing around with file permissions.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies a lot! The problem with running the script as `root` is that I can't connect to this machine as `root` via SSH, and have to do with `admin` privileges. (The whole setup happens via SSH.)

Comment: @DoTheGenes But you do have `sudo` access, so log in as `admin` and run the script as `root` with `sudo`, as I suggested.

Comment: I was under the impression that Packer ran its provisioner scripts as `sudo` (but then why would I need the other `sudo`s, right?), so I thought your answer had already "been applied", so to speak. Anyhow, to run my scripts as `sudo` I'll have to change the `execute_command` Packer parameter to something that'll give me `sudo`.

Comment: @DoTheGenes I see. I'll make an addition to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! You updated your answer just as Dummy00001 came with basically the same answer - and both are good solutions!

Answer (score 2):

As Kusalananda pointed out, the problem is that output redirection happens in the shell which calls `sudo`.

In such situations I generally use this simple trick:

```
TMPFILE=`tempfile`
cat << EOF > $TMPFILE
# Content line 1
# Content line 2
# (...)
EOF
sudo cp $TMPFILE /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
rm $TMPFILE
```

I create a temp file and put content there (no need for sudo for that step). And then with sudo, copy the temp file to the final destination. Finally: delete the temp file. (I use the copy to make the file ownership to belong to the root; the move would keep the user/group of the calling user. Alternatively, one can use the `chmod`/`chown` to fix the permissions.)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was quite simple, and 123's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37877582/shell-complains-about-file-permissions-when-creating-a-config-file#comment63211436_37877582) gave me the right answer: `chown`

By changing this

```
sudo mv /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg.bak
```

to this

```
sudo chown admin /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
sudo chmod 644 /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
sudo cp /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg.bak
```

I now have both the permissions and ownership I need for my setup to work.

**EDIT**

Other users have provided better and more viable solutions, as well as answered some issues around my script.